# Replace a value in query in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next js. I create the url using query params:
`http://localhost:3000/cars?colors=red&nr=20`. Is there a possibility, when i click on the button, to change just a specific part of the url like: `http://localhost:3000/cars?colors=blue&nr=20`. So in this case i just changed the color in blue.
I used:

```js
  router.replace(
      {
        pathname: '/...',
        query:  {
          color: blue
        },
      },
      undefined,
      {
        shallow: true,
      },
    );
```

but it does not work.
 How to solve the issue?

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? the browser didn't update the URL? or your UI color didn't change?

Comment: @SabrinaLuo, the browser update it, but i lose another part of the url: `http://localhost:3000/cars?colors=blue`. You can see that `&nr=20` is lost, i need just to replace a specific part of the url but the items that i don't want to change to keep intact. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you will need to add all the queries into your `router.replace query`, e.g.

```
  router.replace(
  {
    pathname: '/...',
    query:  {
      nr:20,
      color: blue
    },
  },
  undefined,
  {
    shallow: true,
  },
);
```

to make it simpler, you can do

```
  router.replace(
  {
    pathname: '/...',
    query:  {
      ...router.query, // list all the queries here
      color: blue // override the color property
    },
  },
  undefined,
  {
    shallow: true,
  },
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675107/using-redux-with-next-js , could you help?

Comment: could you help please with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410826/get-accesstoken-in-auth0